# Allow write based on the value of a document fileld

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want all authenticated users to read the collection but only the user with the uid that is specified in the field named `uid` should be able to write.

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /taken/{doc}{
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read,write: if request.auth.uid == doc.id;
    }  
  }
}
```

However, the above code does not allow write access even if the query has the right uid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /taken/{doc}{
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow create: if true;  // resource.data is not defined on create, hence the separate case
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }  
  }
}
```

And you can even force the `uid` field to be set on `create`, depending on your logic:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /taken/{doc}{
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;  // Forces uid to be set to the user's uid
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read data of the document being access using `resource` object as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /taken/{doc}{
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.id;
    }  
  }
}
```

The above rules allow any authenticated users to read the documents in 'taken' collection but only user with that UID in the documentation to write it.

Comment: This wont work on `create` as there is no `resource.data` then. And the field is `uid`, not `id`